# I need to reshape epinions dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, reshape

I'm doing my final dissertation in master degree and it's about recommendation systems.
In the first step I need to do kmeans on the dataset.
I use epinions dataset,
My problem is that I have many rows for every user, and
I need to merge all rows for one user into one column.

Example :

```
A = [
    [1  2  3]
    [1  3  4]
    [1  5  1]
]
```

The columns are `userid`, `item num`, `rate`

```
B =
  [1 2 3 3 4 5 1]
```

I need to convert A to B.
I don't know exactly that it's good way to reshape data or not, but I need to have totally one row for one user and not one row for each rating of user

Thanks friends.

Comment: Did you tried the function `reshape`? Here is an example with the inverse transformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876591/reshape-column-vector

Answer (score 0):

To find all rows in `A`, where the user ID is `1`, you can use

```
A(:,1)==userId
```

which returns a column vector, containing a logical true, if the user ID is 1, and a logical false otherwise.
You can use this result and [matrix indexing](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to find all values corresponding to this user ID with

```
tmp = A(A(:,1)==userId, 2:end);
```

The result will in your case be a `3 x 2` matrix containing the desired values. You can flatten this using the [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function. 
As `reshape` reads your data column-wise and then reshapes it, this will change the order of your array. By transposing the input first, the data is taken row-wise. Finally, you'll just have to attach the `userId` at the front of this vector.

```
userPrefs = [userId, reshape(tmp.',1,[])]
```

Result:

```
A = [1  2  3; 1  3  4; 1  5  1];
userId = 1;
tmp = A(A(:,1)==userId, 2:end);
userPrefs = [userId, reshape(tmp.',1,[])];

userPrefs = 
     1     2     3     3     4     5     1
```